# How can I change the highest directory in a git project?

Tags: git

I had a project that I had committed to github, **My Project**. At one point I realized that **My Project** is too large to contain in just one program (i.e. front end & back end), so I wanted to break it up into separate programs, but I still want it to be contained within one repository. I don't want to break up the code within **My Project** and add a new directory within there because it is already a properly configured Android project, I want it to be completely separate from the back end. So what I want is:

**Project Root**: {**MyProject**, **MyProject2**}

Something like that, **Project Root** is the main directory which contains the code for the work I've done so far in **My Project** and **My Project2** is the new work. So **My Project** contains all the Github information and is what gets pushed, instead I want **Project Root** to be what gets pushed to the repository. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you do anything, commit or stash all your changes.

First make a new directory inside your MyProject that you want to contain MyProject. Then move everything except the .git folder into that directory. Then just commit your changes. Git should recognize everything as a move.

Then just rename your directory to the project root and add the new Project2 inside it. You should have the directory structure desired.

From Rohit with additions: Use `git mv ./!(.git) MyProject` (the git part adds all the changes as well)

Comment: This works. As a side note, is there a way in command line to move everything EXCEPT files that contain `.git`?

Comment: @mike Try `mv ./!(.git) MyProject/`, if you're on `bash`

Comment: @RohitJain, amazing! I can't believe I've used bash for almost 15 years without knowing that this was possible!

Comment: @Chris I didn't knew either, until today :)

Comment: @Chris I guess it would also work for a couple or more files: `mv ./!(.git|leave_file1|leave_file2) MyProject/`. Haven't tried it though.